# Why subscription not working in constructor?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following class:

I try to save prev and current state, and replace preve state on current by user click.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class PortalBridgeService {
  private portalsSubject = new Subject<Portal>();
  private prev: Portal;

  readonly portals$ = this.portalsSubject.pipe(
    startWith(portalDefault()),
    pairwise(),
    map(([prev, current]) => ({ prev, current }))
  );
  // States
  readonly currentPortal$ = this.portals$.map((value) => value.current);
  readonly prevPortal$ = this.portals$.map((value) => value.prev);

  constructor() {
    this.prevPortal$.subscribe((prev) => (this.prev = prev));
  }

  activatePortal(type: PortalType) {
    try {
      const portal = portalByType(type);

      if (!portal) throw `There is not found portal with type ${type}`;

      this.setPortal(portal);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  setPortal(portal: Portal) {
    this.portalsSubject.next(portal);
  }

  disposePortal() {
    if (this.prev) {
      this.setPortal(this.prev);
    }
  }
}
```

Template is:

```
<ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="currentPortal$ | async"></ng-template>
```

Why I dont get value in `this.currentPortal$.subscribe((res) => console.log(res));` despite `startWith` emits first value?

I use async in template:

```
currentPortal$ | async
```

**I tried to simplify this to:**

```
export class PortalBridgeService implements OnInit {
  public portalsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Portal>(portalDefault());

  ngOnInit() {
    this.portalsSubject
      .pipe(
        pairwise(),
        map(([prev, current]) => ({ prev, current }))
      )
      .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

`.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));` not working!

Comment: Following from your previous question, didn't you say the subscription needs to be attached to a `click` event? At the moment there is nothing to trigger the subscription. Something must trigger the `portalsSubject` Subject.

Comment: I trigger this by `currentPortal$ | async` in template.
  `readonly currentPortal$ = this.portals$.map((value) => value.current)`

Comment: `async` is a fancy way of subscribing in the template. It isn't much different than the subscription in the constructor. Some value needs to be emitted to the observable like `this.currentPortal$.next(...)`. Again, do you still wish to attach this observable to an element's click event? If so please show the template.

Comment: I have updated my question with full code including temaplte

Comment: Also I wonder how to assign value from `prevPortal$` to `currentPortal$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not correct, is typescript giving you any errors?

```
readonly prevPortal$ = this.portals$.map((value) => value.prev);
```

I think you want:

```
readonly prevPortal$ = this.portals$.pipe(map(v => v.prev));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe Operators will never force the Observable to emit a value.  At some point you'll have to call `next()` to start the process

```
export class PortalBridgeService {
  constructor() {
    this.currentPortal$.subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
    this.portalsSubject.next(); // <---- do this here
  }
}
```

Comment: What if to use `BehaviorSubject` instead Subject?

Comment: I do not think that will change your underlying issue.